# ListView in javafx, adds multiple cells

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx

Debugging for the code below, it shows that the `updateItem()` method is called multiple times, but I am unable to figure out why its being called multiple times.

I wanted to add the Tooltip to the ListView.

```
// THIS TO ADD TOOLTIP, NOT WORKING FULLY.
lstComments.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<String>, ListCell<String>>() {
    @Override
    public ListCell<String> call(ListView<String> p) {
        final Tooltip tt = new Tooltip();
        final ListCell<String> cell = new ListCell<String>() {
            String message = ca.getMessage();

            @Override
            public void updateItem(String s, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(s, empty);
                tt.setText(message);
                setTooltip(tt);
            }
        };

        cell.setText(ca.getMessage());
        return cell;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Recommendation**

I find the usability of Tooltips on ListView cells horrible, because the Tooltips intercept standard mouse events used to select rows, scroll the list, etc.  So I would not recommend placing Tooltips on ListView cells.

**Why multiple cells are created and updateItem is called multiple times**

It is expected that a ListView have multiple cells and that [updateItem()](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/Cell.html#updateItem%28T,%20boolean%29) is potentially called multiple times for each cell.

A cell is created for every row in the ListView that is displayed on the scene, even if some cells are empty.  A couple more cells that are offscreen are usually created for efficient scroll handling.  Each time the underlying data for a ListView is initially set or modified, or the list is scrolled, updateItem() will be invoked on relevant cells to update the cell's contents.  In the case of scrolling a large list, updateItem() will be invoked many, many times for each cell.

**Sample code for setting a Tooltip on ListView Cells**

The code below is based on the [Oracle JavaFX tutorial ListView sample](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/list-view.htm), but customizes it to create Tooltips for cells when you hover over them.

```
mport javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.*;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class ListViewSample extends Application {

    ListView<String> list = new ListView<String>();
    ObservableList<String> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            "chocolate", "salmon", "gold", "coral", "darkorchid",
            "darkgoldenrod", "lightsalmon", "black", "rosybrown", "blue",
            "blueviolet", "brown");
    final Label label = new Label();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        VBox box = new VBox();
        Scene scene = new Scene(box, 200, 200);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("ListViewSample");
        box.getChildren().addAll(list, label);
        VBox.setVgrow(list, Priority.ALWAYS);

        label.setLayoutX(10);
        label.setLayoutY(115);
        label.setFont(Font.font("Verdana", 20));

        list.setItems(data);

        list.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<String>, ListCell<String>>() {
            @Override public ListCell<String> call(ListView<String> list) {
                return new ColorRectCell();
            }
        });

        list.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(
                (ov, old_val, new_val) -> {
                        label.setText(new_val);
                        label.setTextFill(Color.web(new_val));
                });
        stage.show();
    }

    static class ColorRectCell extends ListCell<String> {
        final Rectangle swatch = new Rectangle(30, 30);
        final Tooltip tip = new Tooltip();

        public ColorRectCell() {
            tip.setGraphic(swatch);
        }

        @Override
        public void updateItem(String color, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(color, empty);

            if (color != null) {
                swatch.setFill(Color.valueOf(color.toUpperCase()));
                setText(color);
                setTooltip(tip);
            } else {
                setText("");
                setTooltip(null);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```